# Fill a matrix with sequence of value

Tags: r, matrix, fill

I have this matrix

```
all1 <- matrix(ncol=19,nrow=1356))
```

I want to fill each row with a sequence of this number

`m <- c(4:22)`

The sequence is correcly length 19,like the number of columns of matrix, the length of each row of the matrix.
How i can to do it?

Comment: Try `all1 <- matrix(c(4:22), ncol=19,nrow=1356, byrow = TRUE) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should insert the values in the definition of the matrix, using the  *rep*  function like this:

```
m <- matrix(rep(c(4:22), 1356), ncol=19, nrow=1356, byrow=T)
```

The option  *byrow*  tells R to fill the matrix by row and not by column.

Comment: He doesn't even need `rep` because of the recycling. Note: `byrow=TRUE` and not `Y`

Comment: In addition to the note on recycling, you don't need to name the arguments if you put them in the right order. `matrix(4:22, 1356, 19, TRUE)` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

`matrix` would be the standard way to do this, but you could also use `replicate` (just for fun).

```
t(replicate(1356, 4:22))
```

Or, you can get really cryptic with:

```
t(`dim<-`(rep(c(4:22), 1356), c(19, 1356)))
```

---

Make sure all approaches yield the same results:

```
x <- function() matrix(4:22, 1356, 19, TRUE)
y <- function() t(replicate(1356, 4:22))
z <- function() t(`dim<-`(rep(c(4:22), 1356), c(19, 1356)))

identical(x(), y())
# [1] TRUE
identical(x(), z())
# [1] TRUE
```

... and surprise yourself (or not) with the difference in microseconds...

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(x(), y(), z())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#   x()  293.631  295.639  309.5798  298.3165  327.5460  393.144   100
#   y() 2026.409 2076.166 2337.4346 2121.4595 2332.0885 8593.830   100
#   z()   94.159   98.620  188.2139  103.3070  115.8015 3881.459   100
```